# Ouput of script shows extra comma

Tags: powershell

I have a script where the script check NIC binding order.

```cs
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    function Get-BindOrder {
        $Binding = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage").Bind
        $Return = New-Object PSobject
        $BindingOrder = @()
        foreach ($Bind in $Binding) {
            $DeviceId = $Bind.Split("\")[2]
            $Adapter = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Networkadapter | Where {$_.GUID -eq $DeviceId }).NetConnectionId
            $BindingOrder += $Adapter
        }
        $BindingOrder
    } #EndFunction
    CLS
    Get-BindOrder
}

$adapteresult = $result -join (",")
```

when I echo this `$adapteresult = $result`, I am getting an output as below

```
PS C:\> $adapteresult
vEthernet (10.211.14.0_20)
storage
Ethernet 5
Ethernet 4
Ethernet 2
Ethernet 6
```

The same variable when I added `$adapteresult = $result -join (",")`, I am getting out put with extra command in between.

```
vEthernet (10.241.24.0_21),storage,Ethernet 5,,Ethernet 4,Ethernet 2,Ethernet 6,,
```

I do not want any extra comma in output. Expecting output like below:

```
vEthernet (10.241.24.0_21),storage,Ethernet 5,Ethernet 4,Ethernet 2,Ethernet 6,
```

Comment: There is an empty string in the array.  $adapteresult[$adapteresult.count - 1] should be empty. Remove that one and it will work

Comment: i know what you see but what is the count of the collection? `$result.Count`

Comment: I dont see what you are mentioning about. Can you please show me the line where the editing required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected myself and its working fine now

```
  $a = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage").Bind | ForEach-Object {
          $guid = ($_ -split '\\')[2]
          Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE GUID='$guid'" |
            Select-Object -ExpandProperty NetConnectionID
        }

$b = $a -join","
```

Answer (score 2):

`(Get-WmiObject Win32_Networkadapter | Where {$_.GUID -eq $guid}).NetConnectionId` appears to be returning $nulls that you are capturing in `$BindingOrder`. Displayed on the screen they take up no space but they are there regardless. Running a condensed version of your code locally on my machine ...

```cs
$results = ((Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage").Bind | Foreach-Object {
    $guid = $_.split("\")[2]
    (Get-WmiObject Win32_Networkadapter | Where {$_.GUID -eq $guid}).NetConnectionId
})
```

Using that lets look at `$results`:

```
$results
$results.Count
$results -contains $null

Local Area Connection
6
True
```

On my machine I only have one match for Local Area Connection. However the `$results` have stored 6 items at least one of which is a `$null`. You need to filter out these results it seems in your query.

```
 $Adapter = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Networkadapter | Where {$_.GUID -eq $DeviceId }).NetConnectionId
 if($Adapter){
     $BindingOrder += $Adapter
 }
```

Should do it. if `$adapter` is null or empty string then it won't be added to `$bindingorder`

Comment: Thanks. I am getting correct binding order in this script. But here also when I use $echoresults = $results -join"," command I am getting output with extra comma.  vEthernet (10.211.14.0_20),,storage,Ethernet 6,Ethernet 3,Ethernet 2,Ethernet,,